# Update only integers in a nested loop

Tags: python

```
swim=[['Cycle Shoes+Goggles', 1.25], 
      ['Cycle shoes+Sunglasses', 1], 
      ['Run shoes+Goggles', 1.33]]

swim_s = 50
    
def update1(lst1):
    for i in lst1:
        i[1]*=swim_s
    
update1(swim)
```

Currently, the program will only multiply the first integer by 50, but how would i go about doing it for every integer in the list(The full list will have over 10 integers)

Comment: `1.25` and `1.33` are not integers, maybe the word you're looking for is number? Your code currently multiplies all of them just fine provided that they're the second item in their sub-list. Or do you want to actually only update integers? If so your code would need changes.

Comment: Your code looks like multiplies all numbers in the position 1 of the sublists of `swim`.
What's your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if it's an instance of `int` using `isinstance`:

```py
def update(lst):
    for ele in lst1:
        for i in range(len(ele)):
            if isinstance(ele[i], int):
                ele[i] *= 50
```